# Panoramic display in Carousel Slider, works on mobile, but fails on flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart

I checked on dribble and saw a beautiful image display with a panoramic effect, I thought I should replicate same using flutter using carousel_slider plugin and panorama plugin, surprisingly it  well on mobile, but fails to work on flutter web,on web, start works temporarily and goes blank after a few seconds. please find below code and error response.

```
class _SampleProductCarouselState extends State<SampleProductCarousel> {
  final String imagePath = 'assets/carousel/';
  int _current = 0;
  final CarouselController _controller = CarouselController();

  final List _isHovering = [
    false, false, false, false,
    // false, false, false
  ];
  final List _isSelected = [
    true, false, false, false,
    // false, false, false
  ];
final List<String> images =[

    "assets/carousel/headphone.png",
    "assets/carousel/terraces.jpeg",
    "assets/carousel/furniture.jpeg",
    "assets/carousel/master.jpeg",
    "assets/carousel/bath.jpeg",
    "assets/carousel/bedroom.jpeg",
    // "assets/carousel/hall.jpg",
  ];

  final List<String> products = [
    "FURNITURE",
    "TERRACES",
    "INTERIOR DESIGN",
    "TOILET DESIGN",
    "MASTER BEDROOM",
    "COLLECTIONS",

  ];


  List<Widget>generateImagesTiles(screenSize){
    return images.map((element)=>
        ClipRRect(
          child:  Panorama(
            animSpeed: 10.0,
            animReverse :true,
            interactive: true,

            zoom: 0,
            hotspots: [
              Hotspot(
                latitude: -15.0,
                longitude: -129.0,
                width: 30,
                height: 75,
                //   // widget: hotspotButton(text: "Next scene", icon: Icons.open_in_browser, onPressed: () => setState(() => _panoId++)),
              ),],



            child: Image.asset(element,

              fit: BoxFit.cover,


            ),),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),


        )).toList();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    var imageSliders = generateImagesTiles(screenSize);

    // color: Colors.white,
    // padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
    return Stack(
      children: [
        CarouselSlider(
          items: imageSliders,
          options:CarouselOptions(
              enlargeCenterPage: true,
              aspectRatio: 18 / 8,
              autoPlay: true,
              onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                setState(() {
                  _current = index;
                  for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                    if (i == index) {
                      _isSelected[i] = true;
                    } else {
                      _isSelected[i] = false;
                    }
                  }
                });
              }

          ),
          carouselController: _controller,
        ),
        AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: 18 / 8,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              products[_current],
              style: TextStyle(
                letterSpacing: 8,
                fontFamily: 'Electrolize',
                fontSize: screenSize.width / 25,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),

        ResponsiveWidget.isSmallScreen(context)
            ? Container()
            : AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: 17 / 8,
          child: Center(
            heightFactor: 1,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: screenSize.width / 8,
                  right: screenSize.width / 8,
                ),
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 5,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: screenSize.height / 50,
                      bottom: screenSize.height / 50,
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        for (int i = 0; i < products.length; i++)
                          Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: [
                              InkWell(
                                splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                                hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
                                onHover: (value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    value
                                        ? _isHovering[i] = true
                                        : _isHovering[i] = false;
                                  });
                                },
                                onTap: () {
                                  _controller.animateToPage(i);
                                },
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                      top: screenSize.height / 80,
                                      bottom: screenSize.height / 90),
                                  child: Text(
                                    products[i],
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: _isHovering[i]
                                          ? Colors.blueGrey[900]
                                          : Colors.blueGrey,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Visibility(
                                maintainSize: true,
                                maintainAnimation: true,
                                maintainState: true,
                                visible: _isSelected[i],
                                child: AnimatedOpacity(
                                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                                  opacity: _isSelected[i] ? 1 : 0,
                                  child: Container(
                                    height: 5,
                                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.blueGrey,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                        Radius.circular(10),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    width: screenSize.width / 10,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],


    );
  }
}
```

Error output:

```
======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 1814 pos 12: '!_debugDoingThisLayout': is not true.


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1814:12)
#3      ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:56:11)
#4      RenderFlex._computeSizes (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:829:43)
#5      RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:931:32)
#6      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#7      ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:56:11)
#8      RenderStack._computeSize (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:570:43)
#9      RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:597:12)
#10     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#11     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#12     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#13     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#14     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#15     RenderSliverList.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart:213:28)
#16     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#17     RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:137:12)
#18     RenderSliverPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:371:11)
#19     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#20     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:510:13)
#21     RenderShrinkWrappingViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1938:12)
#22     RenderShrinkWrappingViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1884:20)
#23     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#24     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#25     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#26     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#27     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#28     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#29     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#30     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#31     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#32     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#33     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#34     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#35     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#36     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#37     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#38     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#39     RenderCustomPaint.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_paint.dart:545:11)
#40     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#41     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#42     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#43     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#44     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#45     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#46     RenderCustomPaint.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_paint.dart:545:11)
#47     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#48     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#49     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#50     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#51     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#52     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#53     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#54     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#55     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#56     _RenderLayoutBuilder.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart:321:14)
#57     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#58     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:171:12)
#59     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:1005:7)
#60     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:240:7)
#61     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:403:14)
#62     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#63     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#64     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#65     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#66     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1376:11)
#67     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#68     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#69     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#70     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#71     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#72     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#73     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#74     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#75     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#76     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#77     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#78     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#79     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#80     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#81     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#82     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#83     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#84     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#85     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#86     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#87     RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3430:13)
#88     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#89     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#90     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#91     _RenderTheatre.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:751:15)
#92     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#93     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#94     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#95     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#96     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#97     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#98     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#99     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#100    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#101    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#102    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#103    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#104    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#105    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#106    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#107    RenderView.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:165:14)
#108    RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1731:7)
#109    PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:887:18)
#110    RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:497:19)
#111    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:883:13)
#112    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:363:5)
#113    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
#114    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1081:9)
#115    SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:862:7)
(elided 6 frames from class _AssertionError, class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, and dart:async-patch)
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderFlex#e0d75 relayoutBoundary=up23 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: not positioned; offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...  size: MISSING
...  direction: vertical
...  mainAxisAlignment: start
...  mainAxisSize: min
...  crossAxisAlignment: start
...  textDirection: ltr
...  verticalDirection: down
RenderObject: RenderFlex#e0d75 relayoutBoundary=up23 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  needs compositing
  parentData: not positioned; offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
  size: MISSING
  direction: vertical
  mainAxisAlignment: start
  mainAxisSize: min
  crossAxisAlignment: start
  textDirection: ltr
  verticalDirection: down
...  child 1: RenderConstrainedBox#0688f relayoutBoundary=up24 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    needs compositing
...    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
...    constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...    size: Size(392.7, 791.3)
...    additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, h=791.3)
...    child: RenderPadding#e6a7b relayoutBoundary=up25 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS
```

Comment: Can you please add the Panorama package you used?

Comment: I used panorama: ^0.4.1

Comment: Thanks. Can you include the rest of the widget code? Is there anything in `initState` for example?

Comment: I have eddited the coe to include carousel path, hover list.

Comment: Can you please try to use the Panorama package in a simple widget (not necessarily responsive) and on the web without the Carousel widget and see if it works? This is to find whether the problem is in the carousel package or the Panorama pacakge

Comment: I just used The Panorama plugin on a simple widget and it works well, carousel_slider package works well too as a standard alone .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using the Panorama plugin without the carousel_slider worked for you, I recommend you to not use the carousel_slider package at all. After all, you can do everything this package does yourself using the `PageView` widget.

Here's a slider implementation using `PageView` with animated scaling up for the current slide, try it with the `Panorama` widget and see if it works

```dart
class Carousel extends StatefulWidget {
  const Carousel({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CarouselState createState() => _CarouselState();
}

class _CarouselState extends State<Carousel> {
  late final PageController _pageController;

  int _activePageIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _pageController = PageController(
      initialPage: 0,
      viewportFraction: 0.8,
    );
    super.initState();
  }
  
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 200,
      child: PageView.builder(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        controller: _pageController,
        itemCount: 3,
        onPageChanged: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            _activePageIndex = index;
          });
        },
        itemBuilder: (c, i) {
          return AnimatedScale(
            scale: _activePageIndex == i ? 1 : 0.85,
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            child: Container(
              height: 200,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    blurRadius: 10,
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: const Center(child: Text('foo')), // Add your Panorama widget here
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Check out a live demo for the code above in this DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/b47d79d91deffb6cdcd2a9787e516d87)

[Or see this Gist](https://gist.github.com/Roaa94/b47d79d91deffb6cdcd2a9787e516d87)

Comment: Sorry for the late response Roaa, it worked like a charm. Thank you, i was stuck on this issue for days.